# Barcode printing issue using iText

Tags: javascript, java, itext

I am using iText to dynamically generate PDF docs.I am able to generate the pdf but i am able to print the barcode in below mention format

[image]

but need to print the barcode in below mention format

[image]

Code return of the Barcode generation and PDF is :

```
    public  void generateShipmentItemPDF(ShipmentItemBarcodeVO objShipmentItem) {
        Document document = new Document();

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        ec.responseReset(); // Some JSF component library or some Filter might have set some headers in the buffer beforehand. We want to get rid of them, else it may collide.

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        PdfWriter docWriter = null;
        String fileName =
            "ShipmentItem_PO# " + objShipmentItem.getPoNumber() + "-" + "Line# " + objShipmentItem.getPoNumber() + "-" + "Item# " + objShipmentItem.getItemNumber().trim() + ".pdf";
        LOGGER.info("fileName-: " + fileName);
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition",
                             "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName +
                             "\""); // The Save As popup magic is done here. You can give it any file name you want, this only won't work in MSIE, it will use current request URL as file name instead.
        try{

            docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,  new FileOutputStream("D:\\" + fileName));
            document.open();
//            document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF document."));
//            document.newPage();
//            document.add(new Paragraph("A New Page Hello World PDF document."));

            PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
            code128.setBarHeight(5f);
            code128.setX(0.1f);
            code128.setCode(objShipmentItem.getItemNumber());
            code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
            Image code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
//            code128Image.setAbsolutePosition(10,500);
//            code128Image.scalePercent(50);


            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); 
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);
//            table.setSpacingBefore(100f);
//            table.setSpacingAfter(100f);



            // first row Print 
            String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String texting = objShipmentItem.getSupplierName() + newline +  objShipmentItem.getSupplierAddress().toString().trim() ;

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(texting));
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            cell.setColspan(10);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            table.addCell(cell);
//            table.addCell(code128Image);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Description: " + objShipmentItem.getItemDescription()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantity : " + objShipmentItem.getQuantity()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Country Of Origin : " + objShipmentItem.getCountryOfOrigin()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PO #: " + objShipmentItem.getPoNumber()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);



            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PO Line #: " + objShipmentItem.getPoLine()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);

//            String itemtext = "Item #: " + objShipmentItem.getItemNumber() + newline + code128Image  ;
//            document.add(new Paragraph("Item #: "));
//            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemtext));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(code128Image);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Lot Serial #: "));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Lot Expiration Date: " + sdf.format(objShipmentItem.getLotExpDate())));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Shipment #: "+ objShipmentItem.getShipmentNumber()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell );
            table.addCell(" ");






            document.add(table);
            document.close(); // no need to close PDFwriter?
        }catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can any one help me to display the barcode in correct format

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [How to add an image and text to the same cell?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-add-image-and-text-same-cell) I didn't vote to close this question because (1.) I'm not sure it's a duplicate, (2.) I have a gold badge for iText, so if I vote to close, the question is immediately closed. In any case: the question seems as simple as this: you just need to add the text to a cell, then add the image with the bar code (in the example I refer to, it's the other way around, but a smart developer should be able to adapt the code).

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie : I was about to post something about the _setBaseLine_ method, wouldn't it help placing the text above the bars ?

Comment: That's another option. In that case, you have to make sure the value is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [BarcodeInTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/bar-codes#1616-barcodeintable.java) example. In this example, we add a bar code in two different ways:

[image]

In the first way, we use the `setBaseLine()` method with a negative value to make sure the code is added above the bar code instead of under it:

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setBaseline(-1);
code128.setSize(12);
code128.setCode(code);
code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
Image code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(code128Image);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Note that I removed the `setX()` method and that I defined a different font size to make the barcode look right. I see that you also define a bar height, but the way you add the barcode, it is scaled to match the cell, so you may want to use a different strategy to create the bar code cell.

There are some disadvantages to this method. The first disadvantage is that you'll have to tweak some size parameters to get a good result (maybe also use the `setTextAlignment()` to change the default alignment). The second disadvantage is that you may want to have more freedom with respect to the text you are adding. For instance: you may want to add `PO #:` as is done in your example.

That's why I also provided a second way to add the text and the bar code:

```
code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setFont(null);
code128.setCode(code);
code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Phrase("PO #: " + code));
cell.addElement(code128Image);
table.addCell(cell);
```

In this case, we set the font to `null` so that no text is generated. We add the text to the cell, along with the bar code. Now we have much more freedom to format the text exactly the way we want it.

The `code128Image` is scaled to fit the width of the cell, but you can change this by setting the width percentage of the image, or you can change the width of the column.

Answer (score 1):

The [BarCode](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html) class (and `BarCode128` extends `BarCode`), has a `setBaseLine` method .

It states that providing a negative value, would place the text above the bars :

> *public void setBaseline(float baseline)*
>
> Sets the text baseline. If positive, the text distance under the bars.
>   If zero or negative, the text distance **above** the bars.

Comment: Although this answer was accepted, I think that more information is needed. I have added an extra answer.

Comment: I able to print the number above the  barcode but I am not able to print the  
desc .
                     cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PO Line #: " + objShipmentItem.getPoLine()));
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            table.addCell(cell);
            
            cell.setPadding(5.0f);
            cell.setFixedHeight(40f);
            
            table.addCell(code128Image);
            cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Item No:"));
            table.addCell(cell);

Comment: Look at the answer by @Bruno Lowagie, the second part should help you do that . Also, you could remove my answer as accepted, and accept his one, which is great.

Comment: @Berger Thank you for your comment. Your answer was OK too, hence the up-vote.